# Fredhopper indexed items export/import

Tags: fredhopper

Is there any way (via API, or if not, by directly copying files) to export and import the indexed items from one Fredhopper indexer instance to another?

I can get all the items via the following URL, but don't know how to import them on the other instance: `/fredhopper/query?fh_view_size=all&fh_view=lister`

Both the Indexers are on-prem, FAS version 7.5.0.16 (107262) coupled with SmartTarget 2014 SP1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Export the configuration

> **For Unix:** bin/capture-export INSTANCE-NAME path/to/output.zip -c -i -x -l
>
> **For windows**: bin\capture-export INSTANCE-NAME path/to/output.zip -c -i -x
>   -l

**[Edit]**
Use the -O switch to define the output file name. 
Use any of the options to specify what should be included in the capture: **-c** - config data; **-i** - indices; **-l** -
log files; **-x** - processed XML; **-s** - stack traces of processes.

Import the configuration and reindex the data

> **For Unix:** bin/capture-import INDEXER-INSTANCE /path/to/capture.zip
>
> **For windows** bin\capture-import INDEXER-INSTANCE X:\path\to\capture.zip

Next, you will need to reindex your Fredhopper instance.

```
Unix:       bin/reindex INDEXER-INSTANCE
Windows:    bin\reindex INDEXER-INSTANCE
```

Please verify that your data has been loaded successfully and correctly and that there are no errors in the relevant log files.

After the re-index also required to publish your configuration.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The capture-export also requires an instance name. Any information on what all those parameters mean? As mentioned I only need the indexed items, not the configuration etc.

Btw, am still struggling with this, I get 0KBs for the export packages.

Comment: Instance names you can refer to your topology.txt on [fredhopper-home]\fredhopper\config,  This topology file defines your indexing and live servers, also double check that environment has a processed xml or not on this location fredhopper/data/instances/[instance-name]/data/xml/processed/batch

Comment: Updated the Answers HTML source to visible the Instance-name in the command, it was due to html &gt; and &lt;

Comment: Hm, yeah, that would explain them not showing up in your answer. For "Any information on what all those parameters mean? " I meant to ask about the parameters for the `capture-export`, in other words what do the `-c -i -x -l` mean? When I open the Business Manager I can see indexed items, but will check the files tomorrow and leave an update.

Comment: Updated answers to included the parameters details

Comment: I was able to get the export successfully, must have had a typo the last time I've tried. Thanks.